# How can I flip a buffer vertically during an YUV to RGB conversion

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

**EDIT** : The question was not clear sorry, I updated and added details.

I have a buffer with image data (YUV format) that I convert to an RGB format. The problem is, I would like to flip the image vertically (Invert the Y-position).

What I'm able to do for the moment is convert my YUV data to RGB data in a buffer, then flip this buffer vertically.

**Here is the working code for this :**

```
unsigned char* DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertYUVtoRGB(void* frameBytes)
{
    unsigned char *mycopy = new unsigned char[height*width*3];
    unsigned char *flippedCopy = new unsigned char[height*width*3];
    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;


    //Conversion from YUV to RGB

    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < width * height * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {
        unsigned char v = pData[j];
        unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
        unsigned char u = pData[j+2];

        mycopy[i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        mycopy[i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        mycopy[i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

        y = pData[j+3];
        mycopy[i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        mycopy[i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        mycopy[i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;
    }

    //Vertical flip

    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                flippedCopy[(i + j * width) * 3 + k] = mycopy[(i + (height - 1 - j) * width) * 3 + k];
            }
        }
    }

    return flippedCopy;   
}
```

What I would like to do to gain performance is flip the buffer **DURING** the conversion from YUV to RGB. I had no idea how to do it and Yusuf answer helped me, so here is what I have for the moment :

```
unsigned char* DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertYUVtoRGB(void* frameBytes)
{
    unsigned char *mycopy = new unsigned char[height*width*3];
    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;
    int k = height - 1;

    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < width * height * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {
            unsigned char v = pData[j];
            unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
            unsigned char u = pData[j+2];

            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

            y = pData[j+3];
            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
            mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;

            if (<i multiple of (width*3)-1>){ 
                k = k - 2;
            }

    }

    return mycopy;
}
```

If I'm correct, this should work, assuming the `if` condition is right. But I don't know how to express this `if` condition, since `i` is incremented by 6 each time, so I might "skip" the right moment to decrement `k`

I hope I'm clear enough. Thanks

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: you could use two loops and save them to an other array in an inverted way... like height - i or something

Comment: "Here is the code" OK. And? Does it work? What does it do? What's your question about it?

Comment: The problem appears to be that, at least in the code provided, you're not even attempting to flip the buffer vertically. Did you perhaps forget to include your attempt at solving the problem or else include what concept(s) you're struggling with that's preventing you from making such an attempt in the first place?

Comment: I edited my question to add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that width is even, otherwise "reduce in new line"-if will be complicated, then you must use 2 loops. I didn't tested, but should look like this;

```
unsigned char* DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertYUVtoRGB(void* frameBytes)
{
    unsigned char *mycopy = new unsigned char[height*width*3];
    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;
    unsigned int k = height - 1;

    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < width * height * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {
        unsigned char v = pData[j];
        unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
        unsigned char u = pData[j+2];

        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

        y = pData[j+3];
        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        mycopy[(width*k*3) + i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;

        if (mod(i, width*3) == 0) //reduce in new line (i am not sure how to reduce it, you should think about here)
            k = k - 2;
    }

    return mycopy;
}
```

And tag your question as imageprocessing etc not only as c++